# Using MySQL table values as headers

Tags: php, header, while-loop, mysql

I have a MySQL table with values containing judges for a sports competition. Layout example:

```
Table name = competition

panel   | name | role
Grade 1 | Bob  | Judge 1
Grade 1 | Dave | Judge 2
Grade 2 | Jo   | Judge 1
Grade 1 | Kat  | Judge 3
```

I would like to show this in HTML in the following format:

```
-- Grade 1 --
Judge 1 | Bob
Judge 2 | Dave
Judge 3 | Kat
-- Grade 2 --
Judge 1 | Jo
```

The panel names are variable and change between competition, so using them in code isn't an option. My attempt (which isn't working) is:

```
<?php $panels_distinct = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT panel FROM competition"); ?>

   <table>

<?php while $panel_names = mysql_fetch_array($panels_distinct) { ?>

   <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><?php echo $panel_names['panel'] ; ?></td>
   </tr>

   <?php $judges = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM competition WHERE panel = $panel_names['panel'] ") ; 
   while $judges_info=mysql_fetch_array($judges) { ?>

      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $judges_info['role'] ; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $judges_info['name'] ; ?></td>
      </tr>

   <?php } // end while $judges_info ?>

<?php } // end while $panel_names ?>

   </table>
```

At the moment only the panel names are being output. Any help or suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `DISTINCT` from the sql. Also you want `ORDER BY grade` after the table name.

To get the formatting you showed you need to detect when grade changes in the loop and then print the title row.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you should put single quotes around the value you are comparing:

```
panel = '$panel_names['panel']' " );
```

Another problem is that php doesn't like parsing array keys that have quotes around them when they are embedded in strings. You could surround the array in {}'s:

```
panel = '{$panel_names['panel']}' " );
```